# Sql server insert into giving error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I formed a `INSERT INTO` but it is giving error. I am not being able to capture the error. So please tell me how could I rectify it. Below is my query

```
INSERT INTO UserRights (UserID,Forms_Name,Controls_Name,IsEnabled)
Select 'allison', Select Forms_Name, Controls_Name, IsEnabled
from UserRights Where UserID='testrole'
```

Comment: You have `select` twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO UserRights (UserID,Forms_Name,Controls_Name,IsEnabled) 
Select 'allison', Forms_Name,Controls_Name,IsEnabled 
from UserRights 
Where UserID='testrole'
```

Answer (score 2):

You have two `SELECT`s, use *one* only for both the literal string & the fields;

```
INSERT INTO UserRights ...
select 'allison',Forms_Name,Controls_Name,IsEnabled 
from UserRights 
Where UserID='testrole'
```

Answer (score 2):

Drop the second `select` keyword:

`INSERT INTO UserRights (UserID,Forms_Name,Controls_Name,IsEnabled)
Select 'allison',Forms_Name,Controls_Name,IsEnabled
from UserRights
Where UserID='testrole'`

Answer (score 2):

What do you want to achieve with the second `SELECT`? That can't work, and isn't needed. Try it like this:

```
INSERT INTO UserRights (UserID,Forms_Name,Controls_Name,IsEnabled)
    Select 'allison', Forms_Name, Controls_Name, IsEnabled
        from UserRights Where UserID='testrole'
```

Comment: double `select`, you mean? :-)

Answer (score 1):

You have error right here:

```
Select 'allison',Select Forms_Name
```